# Trying to insert an array into a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add every cart item into a column (text box) but i can't seem to use "<<" which is a bitwise operator. Is there a way to add every cart item for the order so all the items will appear in the "products" column.

```
 class OrdersController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :extract_shopping_cart, :only => [:new, :show]

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.total = @shopping_cart.total
    @order.sub_total = @shopping_cart.subtotal
    @order.sales_tax = @shopping_cart.taxes
    @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each do |cart|
      @order.products << cart.item
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  def extract_shopping_cart
   shopping_cart_id = session[:shopping_cart_id]
   @shopping_cart = session[:shopping_cart_id] ? ShoppingCart.find(shopping_cart_id) : ShoppingCart.create
   session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
  end
```

EDIT: @shopping_cart is from the gem [acts_as_shopping_cart](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart)

My Order model is as follows

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :total, :sub_total, :sales_tax, :products

  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have an error:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

Sample code: https://github.com/atbyrd/Bootstrapped_Devise

Comment: What does your Order model look like?  Where did @shopping_cart come from and what does it look like?

Comment: What happens when you use '<<' ? Nothing is added or you get an error?

Comment: If you type in your console: '@order.products.class', what does it give you?

Comment: do you have a product model?

Comment: Yes. i have the product model.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relationship between Order and Product. The way you're writing it, it looks like Order **has_many** products and Product can belong to many Orders. I don't see that reflected in your Order model. 
In other words, you would have to use has_and_belongs_to_many, like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :total, :sub_total, :sales_tax, :products

  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  belongs_to :user
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```

The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) does a great job of describing how this works with charts and everything.

Comment: Do i need to create a new table with column order_id and product_id ?
An example is: https://github.com/atbyrd/Bootstrapped_Devise

Comment: Oh, ok. In the URL the tables already have the relationship. But you did not post it.

Comment: If you type in your console: 
>  Order.new.products.class 

what does it give you?

Comment: The output result gives me: jruby-1.7.12 :002 > Order.new.products.class
  orders Columns (37.0ms)  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `orders`
 => NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making products a column, it's probably better to add a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between orders and products so that Rails will have by default an

```
order.products
```

array and also a

```
product.orders
```

array, where "order" and "product" refer to an instantiated Order or Product with a unique id. This also makes filtering by order or product easy because say you want all the products for a specific order, you could do so by doing something like

```
@products = Order.find(session[:some_id]).products
```

to find all products for the order with the specified id, and you could do a similar thing for the products.orders array. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: exactly what this code is trying to achieve: github.com/atbyrd/Bootstrapped_Devise It has a separate table with both orders and product ID. Though the code in the URL above is hard to explain as there is no action that actually uses the "OrdersProducts" table.

Hope i get an explaination on your idea.